# php mysql join usage

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
$user_res_get = do_mysql_query("SELECT /* forums.php */ userid, subject, " .
    " forumid FROM topics WHERE id=$topicid") or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__);
```

and:

```
$user_res_get = do_mysql_query("SELECT /* forums.php */ id, name, FROM " .
    "forums WHERE id=$forumid") or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__);
```

forumd and id are identical

How to "JOIN" them ?

I tryed create something like this:

```
$user_res_get = do_mysql_query("SELECT u.userid, u.subject, u.forumid, a.id, " .
    "a.name FROM topics AS u JOIN forums as a ON u.forumid = a.id WHERE " .
    "u.forumid=$topicid") or sqlerr(__FILE__, __LINE__);
```

But no luck :/
Any suggestions ?
EDIT:
Ant tryed to print with:

```
$user_row_get = mysql_fetch_assoc($user_res_get);
$user_row_get['subject']
$user_row_get['name']
```

and others...

Comment: you don't need 'AS' after table name it is enough its alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
WHERE u.forumid=$topicid
```

try:

```
WHERE u.id=$topicid
```